# Menu not updating (SwiftUI bug?)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm using macOS Montery Beta 4 along with Xcode 13 Beta 4, and I think I've discovered a bug in `SwiftUI`.

When using a `CommandGroup` along with a button that is enabled/disabled based on a condition, the `CommandGroup` doesn't update. `CommandMenu` does however.

### Reproduction:

1. Create a new SwiftUI macOS project
2. Paste the following code in the `App` file:

```
class Test: ObservableObject {
    @Published var num = 0
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject private var test = Test()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(test)
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Test menu item")
                }
                .disabled(test.num == 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Paste the following code in the `ContentView` file:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var test: Test
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            test.num += 1
        }) {
            Text(String(test.num) + " ---------")
        }
    }
}
```

4. Run the app, and click on the `File` menu. You should see that "Test menu item" is disabled as expected.
5. Click on the button. This simply increments a number by 1. However, "Test menu item" is still disabled, even though `test.num` != 0.

The thing is, replacing the `CommandGroup` with `CommandMenu("Test menu")` fixes it.

All the app does is have a menu item that is disabled if a number is zero. Pressing the button makes that number not zero, but the menu item stays disabled.

Is anybody able to reproduce this, and is this a bug on my part?

Comment: With a similar sort of sample app, I'm having this issue on Big Sur however I don't see this issue on another machine running the latest Monterey beta. To support older OS's though, I'll probably have to use the workarounds here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a minor variation of @George_E answer, is this:

```
 CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
       TestView(test: test)
 }
 
 struct TestView: View {
     @ObservedObject var test: Test
  
     var body: some View {
         Button(action: {}) {
             Text("Test menu item")
         }
         .disabled(test.num == 0)
     }
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you can make it better, well done! I saw `test.num` not making updates so I tried the `onReceive(_:perform:)` approach, but maybe `test` was updating so this works? Odd bug

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect that to be intended behaviour. However, I have found a workaround to fix this.

It's odd that `onChange(of:perform:)` isn't run when `test.num` changes, but we can still detect the publisher. So I split this into a separate view and when the view receives a new value, the button is updated.

Code:

```
CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
    TestView(pub: test.$num)
}
```

```
struct TestView: View {
    let pub: Published<Int>.Publisher
    @State private var disabled = true

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Test menu item")
        }
        .disabled(disabled)
        .onReceive(pub) { new in
            disabled = new == 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really hope this gets fixed soon