# onDeleteCommand menu item is always enabled

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm using macOS Monterey Beta 5 with Xcode 13 Beta 5, and I'm having an issue with `onDeleteCommand`. Basically, its menu item doesn't disable even when no items are selected.

I tried `deleteDisabled`, but it doesn't help.

Here's how to reproduce:

1. Create a new blank SwiftUI macOS project
2. Paste the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
    @State var selection: Set<String> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .onDeleteCommand {
                data.removeAll(where: selection.contains) // Removes selected items
                selection.removeAll()
            }
            .deleteDisabled(selection.isEmpty) // This doesn't help either
            Text("Second Panel")
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run the app, and select an item.
4. Go to the menu, and press Edit -> Delete. Now the selected item should be gone, but the Edit -> Delete menu item is still enabled.

What can I do to solve this issue (Get the menu item to disable itself)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible method is to force update the UI by changing the view's ID. We should only change this when necessary, i.e. after each deletion.

I created a `@State` variable `lastForcedId`, which is given a different value each time the `onDeleteCommand` is run.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var data = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
    @State private var selection: Set<String> = []
    @State private var lastForcedId = UUID()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .onDeleteCommand {
                data.removeAll(where: selection.contains) // Removes selected items
                selection.removeAll()
                lastForcedId = UUID()
            }
            .id(lastForcedId)

            Text("Second Panel")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works well, but I'm wondering is this intended SwiftUI behavior? (Like is this a SwiftUI bug?)

Comment: @recaptcha Likely a SwiftUI bug. I made a similar answer I think sorta recently about a similar issue. Unfortunately this is the current way to solve this (but Apple have actually previously solved update bugs like this)

Comment: ah ok. I submitted a bug report to apple about this. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @recaptcha Found my answer I was referencing ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553497/9607863)), albeit my answer was not the best one. The notable thing is that for some odd reason, in that example, `onChange` wasn't called - meaning SwiftUI is not keeping track of `@State` as it normally should in a view in certain cases. This is related because it's about the menu bar UI of the app not updating.

Comment: I think apple actually fixed that menu bar issue in Beta 5 (I submitted a bug report about that issue a while ago).

Comment: @recaptcha Not so much a bug as a lack of documentation. Changing a view's identity can have surprising consequences, so see my answer for a more "supported" approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69319990/18388

Answer (score 4):

The documentation doesn't spell this out (I filed a report), but you can pass `nil` as the action to most (all?) `on*Command(perform:)` modifiers to explicitly disable the associated menu item. This slightly-rewritten `ContentView` should get the right behavior:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var data = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]
    @State var selection: Set<String> = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data, id: \.self, selection: $selection) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .onDeleteCommand(perform: selection.isEmpty ? nil : deleteSelection)
            Text("Second Panel")
        }
    }

    private func deleteSelection() {
        data.removeAll { selection.contains($0) }
        selection.removeAll()
    }
}
```

While the effect may essentially be the same as in the accepted answer, passing `nil` instead of an action block is a more reliable approach in general, since changes to view identity can sometimes have surprising consequences.